# iOS project with (just a little) Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, ios, unity-game-engine

The standard way to develop with Unity 3D is to develop in the Unity 3D IDE and have it generated Xcode projects when necessary. If we need UIKit support or other Cocoa-Touch features, we need to write pluggins or wrappers for bridging.

Is it possible that we build the overall structure with Cocoa-Touch and Objective-C and only leverage the 3D capabilities of Unity 3D in some certain occasions?

Answer (score 0):

If Unity automatically wraps your entire 3D project inside an Obj-C project, then no, it's not possible.

Why not just accomplish what you're trying to do within the game? Unity supports a lot of various .NET libraries - surely you could just accomplish what you need within Unity itself?

Answer (score -1):

I agree, just use Unity , or don't use unity, its very complex to mix SDKs together